# custom FFT library vs FFTW library produce different results for Poisson Solution Spectral Gradient

Tags: partial-derivative, poissons-equation, fast-fourier-transform

I am trying out different FFT solvers, with two of them being FFTW (fftw version 3.3.3.8, https://www.fftw.org/index.html) and FAST FFT ( [https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~ooura/fft.html](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Eooura/fft.html)).

I am using DCT/inverse DCT to accomplish the following:

(1) **solve a discrete Poisson equation on an NxN map** => result is same between FFTW, FFT

(2) I multiply the DCT result with the wave numbers **to obtain the two spectral derivatives** (in x and y) and compare with the numerical derivatives of the Poisson Equation solution (latter computed using finite differences).

My issue is that (2) gives me a different result when I try FFTW. The spectral gradient is inverted and goes negative for 1/2 of the map.

I am multiplying the 2D map grid points with **pi x i/N** (wavelets), where i is the index of the square (in x and y). I also tried multiplying the 2nd half by **pi x (i - (N - 1))/N** and combinations thereof, to "corrrect" the result, but did not make any progress.

Code is 100% identical for both FFT, FFTW.

Result looks perfect with FAST FFT code I used ([https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~ooura/fft.html](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Eooura/fft.html)), but perturbed with FFTW. I am sure it is something to do with the coefficients and what FFTW expects/orders frequencies?

Any idea why this happens?

I attach two screenshots showing the FFTW, FFT spectral gradient result against the numerical gradient (identical for both as the poisson solution is indeed identical).

[FFTW x-coord spectral gradient vs x-coord Numerical gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPZhZ.gif)

[Fast FFT x-coord spectral gradient vs x-coord Numerical gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDZzf.gif)

Comment: I did some 2D experiments between Fast FFT and FFTW for DCT and IDCT. For DCT results are identical but scaled. For the IDCT, where results looked very different,  by applying the following scaling matrix to the Fast FFT IDCT input: [1 2 ... 2; 2 4 ... 4; ... ;2 4 .. 4] and then multiply the FFTW result by 4, I get the exact same results for the IDCT.

Thus, I am very puzzled as to why my original question, as everything seems to be perfectly scaled in my DCT and IDCT code for the two FFT solvers.